# Unnumbered part with "Part" header

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am writing a thesis, whose outline is a bit treelike, so I would like to have a trunk part (that contains several chapters) and several branches (also containing some chapters).

I changed the name of the parts using

```
\renewcommand\partname{Trunk}
\part{Polish groups}
```

and then

```
\renewcommand\partname{Branch}
\part{The first branch},
```

this works fine.

However, since there is only one trunk, I would like the trunk part not to be numbered Trunk 1. Also, I would like the branches to start being numbered from Branch 1 (and not Branch 2).

But when I write

```
\part*{Polish groups},
```

only the title "Polish groups" appears on the page, with no indication "Trunk" like it would do with "Part 1".

Do you know how to do this?
Thanks.

Edit.
Here is a (hopefully) compilable code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}

    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{ucs}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{ stmaryrd }
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[initials, shortalphabetic]{amsrefs}
    \usepackage{footnote}

      \title{Thèse}
    \author{}

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents


    \renewcommand\partname{Trunk}
    \part{Polish groups}

    \renewcommand\partname{Branch}
        \part{First branch}

\part{Second branch}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, since you don't need numbering, you could do it manually: `{\Huge Trunk \par Polish groups\par}. But maybe i didn't understand the question correct. Can you expand the code snippets to a compilable example, so we have some code *and* output and can understand what you mean?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The idea would be not to do it manually so that the trunk part still appears a part in the table of contents, with the only change that "Part 1. Polish groups" be replaced by "Trunk. Polish groups". I hope I am being clearer. (Also, I don't know  how to add an output to the question.)

Answer (score 3):

From line 867 to 897 of **amsbook.cls** class is where the `\partname`, `\thepart` and `\part` are defined. Correspond to the problem that the number is not needed for **Trunk**, we can redefine the `\thepart` to be empty. And to the problem that the next part must number from one, we just reset the counter **part** to **0**.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\begin{document}

    \renewcommand\thepart{}
    \renewcommand\partname{Trunk}
    \part{Polish groups}

    \setcounter{part}{0}
    \renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
    \renewcommand\partname{Branch}
    \part{First branch}

    \part{Second branch}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.  Also it is a good idea providing a complete document including the sample code that people can easily run to check for correctness.

Comment: Why `\edef`? Neither `\thepart` nor `partname` needs expansion as it's defined (at the moment)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, you are right! There is no expansion needed. Either primitive **TeX** command `\def` or the **LaTeX** command `\renewcommand` is enough :)

Comment: @AndrewSwann Nice comment (y) I will edit it now.

Comment: Unfortunately, with this solution the table of contents does not look correct: a spurious dot appears between “Trunk” and “Polish groups”.  This calls for a patch to the `\@part` command (modify `\addcontentsline…`) which may be document-class dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Special care must be taken, of course, in order to produce the correct output also in the table of contents.  The `\@part` command, as defined in the *amsbook* document class, issues an `\addcontentsline` command as follows:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname\ \thepart. \protect\enspace\protect\noindent#1}%
```

As you can see, a period is added after `\thepart`; thus, redefining the latter command to produce no output is not enough: a patch to the above code in `\@part` would also be necessary, whose details may depend on the document class.

But you can also make up for this problem with a quick trick, which is illustrated by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begingroup
    \renewcommand*\partname{}
    \renewcommand*\thepart{\unskip Trunk}
    \part{Polish groups}
\endgroup
\setcounter{part}{0}
\chapter{Aaaaaa}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Bbbbbb}
\lipsum[2]

\renewcommand*\partname{Branch}
\part{First branch}
\chapter{Cccccc}
\lipsum[3-4]
\chapter{Dddddd}
\lipsum[5-6]

\part{Second branch}
\chapter{Eeeeee}
\lipsum[7]
\chapter{Ffffff}
\lipsum[8]

\end{document}
```

This alternative is less tricky than it might seem at first sight: after all, you could actually think of the word “trunk” as the “number” of the first part, but a “number” that, being a noun in itself, and not a numeral adjective, does not require another noun on which it depends.  Note that `\unskip` is necessary to remove the preceding space.  The `.toc` file will contain the line

```
\contentsline {part}{\ \unskip Trunk. \enspace \noindent Polish groups}{3}
```

which shows that the spacing will look right in the table of contents too.